# how to set and use multiple parameters in single environmental variable in fish shell

Tags: fish

I want to use following in `fish` shell:

```
$ export arm='ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-'
$ make $arm
```

This works fine in `bash/zsh` but *not* on `fish` shell.

But if I execute the following in `fish` shell:

```
$env tmp=arm make
```

this works fine.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

You're looking for `set -x`:

```
set -x arm 'ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-'
```

See the [tutorial section on environment variables](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_exports) for more.

Comment: Though it sounds like it's what the OP is asking, I don't think it  is what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

In `sh`/`bash`:

```
export arm='ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-'
make $arm
```

Doesn't really make sense. Environment variables are meant as variables passed to `make` (so a reference to $(arm) in the Makefile for instance expands to its content). Environment variables are scalar, they can contain only one string value. Above you're relying on the split+glob operator *of the shell* that splits the variable into words passed to `make` (as arguments).

But `$arm` is expanded by the shell, so you don't need to export `arm` to the environment of `make` because `make` makes no use of that `$arm` variable.

Also, on a shell that supports them, it would make more sense to use arrays. In `bash` /`zsh`/`ksh`:

```
arm=(ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-)
make "${arm[@]}"
```

With `fish`:

```
set arm ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-
make $arm
```

With `rc`/`es`/`zsh`:

```
arm=(ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-eabi-)
make $arm
```