# Fish Shell: How to set multiple environment variables from a file using export

Tags: shell, fish

Is it possible to set environment variables with export in Fish Shell?  I am working on a project that configures variables this way and it does not make sense to maintain a separate configuration file just for fish.

Consider this example in bash:

`echo -e "foo=1\nfoobar=2\n" > foo; export $(cat foo | xargs);  env | grep foo`

```
   foo=1
   foobar=2
```

In fish shell, it appears that it will only set a single variable, and only if there is one variable in the file:

`~ $ echo -e "foo=3\nfoobar=4" > foo; export (cat foo | xargs); env | grep foo`

`~ $ echo -e "foo=3" > foo; export (cat foo | xargs); env | grep foo`

```
   foo=3
```

Is this just a flaw / omission in the Fish implementation of export?

This question is similar to but different from these other two posts:

- [Share environment variables between bash and fish](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176322/share-environment-variables-between-bash-and-fish)
- [how to set and use multiple parameters in single environmental variable in fish shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137542/how-to-set-and-use-multiple-parameters-in-single-environmental-variable-in-fish)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I realize that fish uses `set`, but given that `export` is a builtin in bash, and there is no binary to fallback to, where else would it be coming from?  My example above showed that it worked for a single argument but not two.  If not for this detail, fish could be used in more teams that primarily use bash.

Comment: Your bash example doesn't work for me; did you mean `export $(cat foo | xargs)`?

Comment: @zanchey: too many back and forth edits, I have updated the bash example to use the `$` in  `$(cat foo | xargs)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example almost works perfectly - it's not `export` that's the problem, but the use of `xargs`.

Try:

```
echo -e "foo=3\nfoobar=4" > .env; export (cat .env);  env | grep foo
```

The reason is that a command substitution separates arguments on newlines, and `xargs` removes them:

```
> count (cat .env | xargs)
1
> count (cat .env)
2
```

Comment: Why does it work from bash though?

Comment: Bash separates command substitution arguments on space, not newline. Newline isn't perfect - you can embed newlines in file names - but it's a lot better. Otherwise you get funny problems with files with embedded spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In fish, I'd expect you to get an error for `export`:

```
$ echo -e "foo=1\nfoobar=2\n" > foo; export (cat foo | xargs);  env | grep foo
bash: --: command not found...
fish: echo -e "foo=1\nfoobar=2\n" > foo; export (cat foo | xargs);  env | grep foo
                                         ^
```

If you have a file with `variable=value` lines and you want to use that to set environment variables:

```
$ cat foo
foo=1
foobar=2

$ source (sed -rn 's/^([^=]+)=(.*)/set -x \1 \2/p' foo | psub)
$ set -x | grep foo
foo 1
foobar 2
```

Comment: I merged the `export` function in 2.2.0 (with thanks to Rack Lin).